# Comsol not working properly

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, unity-dash

I am not sure if this is a right place to ask this question, if it is not please redirect me to a forum where I might find a solution to this problem. 
I have recently installed Comsol and I am not able to run it. It only works by running it through the terminal but there are no icons available to run from the desktop or the unity menu.Please help, I'm relatively new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just navigate there in your file browser, right-click on executable and press "make link". After that - drag`n drop your link to desktop.

usually comsol is here: /usr/local/comsol50/multiphysics/bin/comsol

otherwise look for it via

> locate -b comsol